# Setting a negative value for the center of a polar plot MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates

Using MATLAB I would like to plot antenna radiation pattern whose maximum value is set to 0. The remaining values are negative and 0 should be at the outermost circle in a polar plot. If I use regular polar() function negative values are put on the opposite side of where it should be. Thus, the polar plot looks like it is flipped. I don't want that. I want maximum value, which is 0 to be at the outermost circle, whereas the remaining negative values are towards the center, not at the opposite side. You can see an example plot down below. How can I accomplish drawing such a polar plot? I would appreciate your help.[image]

Comment: so the values are between [-Inf;0] right? could you please provide a part of the data. have you tried plot(db2mag(values))

Comment: Post a small example that reproduces the problem

Comment: it looks like you also want a scale in dB, something the standard `polar` plot does not accommodate either. Every time I have to use polar plots for a given case I have to make a custom modified version of `polar.m` which suit my needs. If you don't feel you can do that, your best bet is to use one of the more specialized "polar" plotter from the Matlab exchange (for example: [Advanced Polar Plots](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4189-advanced-polar-plots) )

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses. @Finn Yes the values are between [-Inf, 0]. @Finn and @Luis Mendo I would like to plot `y = [-7.23115481293784e-05 -0.000499989477168517 -0.000519580145685205 -0.000228181236066555 -1.78279461177483e-05 -0.000372481833086864 -0.000528975624004579 -0.000181719656382129 0 -2.18963598082959e-05]` and I use `polar(0:(2*pi)/9:2*pi,y*(10^5)/2, '-<r');` @Hoki I don't feel like I can modify the code, I guess I can look for code from exchange. However, if you guys know any trick that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rlim seems to do the trick:

```
            theta=linspace(0,2*pi,200);
            %% The pattern has negative values
            pattern = 10*log10(abs(1+exp(1j*17*sin(theta))));
            %% Makes the max of the pattern 0
            pattern=pattern-max(pattern);
            %% Plots the figure
            figure
            pax = polaraxes;
            polarplot(theta,pattern)
            %% This is what you want. Add a little bit of extra space after the minimum and maximum value
            rlim([min(pattern)-3 max(pattern)+1])
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your answer.